# Typescript Constructor Parameters. Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'public'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I wanted to create class in typescritp + react
I decided to use [Typescript constructor parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties)
But I have an error during compilation when i do that.

That is my UserData class

```
enum SecurityRole {
    USER = "USER",
    ADMIN= "ADMIN"
}
export class UserData {
    constructor(public name: string, readonly securityRole = SecurityRole.USER) { }
}
export const createUserDataFromJson = (json: any): UserData => {
    console.log(`user from json : ` + json)
    return new UserData(json.name, json.securityRole)
}
```

But i have received an error:

```
  Line 8:17:  Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'public'

   6 | }
   7 | export class UserData {
>  8 |     constructor(public name: string, readonly securityRole = SecurityRole.USER) { }
     |                 ^
   9 | }
  10 | export const createUserDataFromJson = (json: any): UserData => {
  11 |     console.log(`user from json : ` + json)
```

I figured that it might be someting with tsconfig.json so here it is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I am using `npm run build` this is `react-scripts build` in my project (4.0.2)

npm version `6.14.6`
node version `v12.18.3`

Have i done anything wrong there? or is it something with my project settings?

Comment: [TypeScript is perfectly happy with that code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAysDGYBOBLALgTwEoHsA2wUA3gFBTlQCqMAollALxQBE1dzANGRQIIAiAWQCSAOSbN+wkcxIBfEsAAeABxxI0UeHgCGAZ11VdwJH21ptxbuXg4QutEjDw0agBTKwAIzwp4UENoQwABcUPaoIADmHFBIwNoAJrZ4GGEIyOjY+IRMcIiomLgEAHRsWACUxFDy8kqq6pq29ppxZsCURiZm2gBiSDgQAFK6toxQrgBWIyCh2iAY5aEdxqbmjAB8lhSNdtnFeDiRrgAGYJ1QAGb90FOjocdQANRQtyDlVrHAaMgg-sAA7oYVt1JtNigEgjFXsUjPlMkVgO9ZEA). JavaScript would give you that error (if the `enum` is actually elsewhere), but that's perfectly valid TypeScript code.

Comment: Are you sure the file is being parsed as TypeScript? What's the file extension?

Comment: T.J. Crowder  thats is .ts file.
and i have also tried it out in that online compiler so i figured thats something with my project settings

Comment: That might also be important :
I am using npm run build -> this is "react-scripts build" in my project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was manage to fix that by adding eslintConfig to my package.json

```
 "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
```